# Add extra attribute to many-to-many join table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, many-to-many

I have to models User and GeoScene with a many-to-many relation via `has_and_belongs_to_many :users/:geo_scenes`. In a user form, one can assign rights for accessing geo_scenes to the user. All geo_scenes are listed with a checkbox - for each checked geo_scene a record in the join table `geo_scenes_users` is created after sending the form:

```
--- First User ---

Geo Scene One   [ ]
Geo Scene Two   [x]
Geo Scene Three [ ]
```

Current form:

```
= form_for(@user) do |form|
...
  = hidden_field_tag("user[geo_scene_ids][]", nil)
    - GeoScene.all.each do |s|
      .checkbox
         %label
           = check_box_tag("user[geo_scene_ids][]", s.id, s.id.in?(@user.geo_scenes.collect(&:id)))
           = s.name
```

Controller takes strong params:

```
  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, { geo_scene_ids:[] })
  end
```

Now the question:

How can i manipulate an extra boolean attribute `write` within the join table. There should be a second checkbox at each GeoScene allowing update `write`. A sample row of geo_scenes_users looks as the following:

```
user_id | geo_scene_id | write
------------------------------
1       | 1            | true
```

I guess i need to remove the `has_and_belongs_to_many` shortcuts and build an extra join model. But how do i manage the checkbox lists in the form then?

```
--- First User ---

Geo Scene       read  write
---------------------------
Geo Scene One   [x]   [ ]
Geo Scene Two   [x]   [x]
Geo Scene Three [ ]   [ ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your form is not going to change. Just add join model and associations. `collection_singular_ids=(ids)` method (`geo_scene_ids=(ids)` in your case) is available for both `has_and_belongs_to_many` and `has_many associations`.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-many-association-reference

```
class GeoScenesUser # join model
  belongs_to :geo_scene
  belongs_to :user
end

class User
  has_many :geo_scenes_users
  has_many :geo_scenes, through: :geo_scenes_users
end
```

After that you will have `User#geo_scene_ids=(ids)` method available, that will work when you pass `geo_scene_ids` from the form, as you did with `has_and_belongs_to_many`